# CR2477 battery peak pulse

Tags: current-measurement

Do you think CR2477 battery can handle 12mA pulse current for 3-4 seconds hourly. How long do you think the battery will last?

Comment: It will handle but the capacity goes to about half. Much better would be drain the peaks from capacitor.

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Unfortunately, this is too general a question. Please edit it and add a good and detailed explanation of what you are doing and importantly why you are doing it. (Don't add info in comments as it's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum). You'll be able to attract better and more useful answers that way. Otherwise, 'do you think it can handle' is too open to interpretation, like 'do you think bricks are too heavy' or such like. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: Was about to upvote, alas, the details I appreciate were (plausible) assumptions in [ElectronicsStudent's answer](/a/691416/274544), already.

Answer (score 1):

**With the following design parameters:**

- Peak-Current 20mA
- Peak-Duration 5s/60min
- Voltage nom. 3V
- Voltage min. 2.5V
- IBatteryMax 2.5mA

**I would come up with the following circuit:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCPHqd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- The peak is supplied from the capacitor C1
- C1 is charged from the battery
- R1 limits the maximum charge current

**Based on the following equations:**

- Imax * PeakDuration / ( Vnom - Vmin ) = C1 = 100mAS / 0.5V = 0.2F
- ( VNom - VCapMin ) / IBatteryMax   = R = 0.5V / 2.5mA = 200Ohm
- Tau = R1 * C1 = 200Ohm * 0.2F = 40s -> 5Tau = 200s = ~3,5min (Charge time for C1 0V->3V)

**Note:**

- Energy is wasted during the charge cylce in R1 - you an use a trickle charger IC
- The Capacitor will never be truly charged to VBat, as it as an e-function
- The Circuit allows to safely swap the battery during operation (Nice feature!)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Good Point! Edited the answer

Comment: At initial connect, inrush \$I_{bat} = V_{nom}/(R1+R_{ser_{C1}})\$.